# Как удалить повторяющиеся элементы из двумерного списка?

Tags: python, list

```
list = [['03:30', 70.0], ['03:30', 135.0], ['03:30', 200.0], ['03:30', 280.0], 
['04:00', 360.0], ['04:00', 430.0], ['04:30', 473.0], ['04:30', 573.0]]
```

Как удалить элементы с одинаковым временем и оставить с большим числом, чтобы получилось:

```
list = [['03:30', 280.0], ['04:00', 430.0], ['04:30', 573.0]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [49]: from itertools import groupby

In [50]: res = [max(g) for _,g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0])]

In [51]: res
Out[51]: [['03:30', 280.0], ['04:00', 430.0], ['04:30', 573.0]]
```

можно явно указать ключ для функции `max()`:

```
In [53]: res = [max(g, key=lambda x: x[1]) for _,g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0])]

In [54]: res
Out[54]: [['03:30', 280.0], ['04:00', 430.0], ['04:30', 573.0]]
```

Данный код группирует список списков по первому элементу:

```
In [57]: for k,g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0]):
    ...:     print(k, list(g))
    ...:
03:30 [['03:30', 70.0], ['03:30', 135.0], ['03:30', 200.0], ['03:30', 280.0]]
04:00 [['04:00', 360.0], ['04:00', 430.0]]
04:30 [['04:30', 473.0], ['04:30', 573.0]]
```

после этого мы выбираем в каждой группе элемент (список) с максимальным вторым элементом:

```
In [58]: for k,g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0]):
    ...:     print(max(g, key=lambda x: x[1]))
    ...:
['03:30', 280.0]
['04:00', 430.0]
['04:30', 573.0]
```

Comment: Не понимаю как этот код работает, но он работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @НетИмени, добавил небольшое пояснение в ответ...

Comment: @НетИмени работает - не трогай.

Comment: @Alban, да я и не трогал как бы ... ;)

Comment: @MaxU а, я промахнулся с получателем)

Comment: а происходит все просто, все элементы пакуютса в тюпл где первый элемент являтса уникальным, второй являетса итератором всех неуникальных по первому элементу. А далее функцией макс, выбираетса максимальный из списка не уникальных.

Answer (score 4):

Если исходить их того что данные у вас отсортированы по времени и значению можно сделать так:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data = [['03:30', 70.0], ['03:30', 135.0], ['03:30', 200.0], ['03:30', 280.0],
        ['04:00', 360.0], ['04:00', 430.0], ['04:30', 473.0], ['04:30', 573.0]]
res = list(OrderedDict(data).items())
print(res)
```

Comment: ну наверное и обычным словарем можно было бы обойтись, однако - браво )

Answer (score 3):

ну вот вариант без "тяжелой артиллерии"

```
list = [['03:30', 70.0], ['03:30', 135.0], ['03:30', 200.0], ['03:30', 280.0], ['04:00', 360.0],
        ['04:00', 430.0], ['04:30', 473.0], ['04:30', 573.0]]
list.sort(reverse=True)
list2 = [list[0]]
for key,value in list:
    if key != list2[-1][0]:
        list2.append([key,value])
```

результат в list2.
Вообще можно было бы написать цикл начиная со второго элемента:

```
for key,value in list[1:]:
    ...
```

Но оно бы запутывало глаз...

Answer (score 2):

Ну а если не иcходить из того что данные отсортированы, то:

```
data = [['03:30', 70.0], ['03:30', 135.0], ['03:30', 200.0], ['03:30', 280.0],
        ['04:00', 360.0], ['04:00', 430.0], ['04:30', 473.0], ['04:30', 573.0]]

data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
res = list(dict(data).items())
```

Как это работает, список конвертируется в словарь, особеностью которого является то, что ключ уникален. Это дает приимущество в том, что при повторном элементе, мы каждый раз заменяем его дублирующимся в списке. Собственно, для этого сортировка и нужна, чтобы последним в списке оказался тот, который нам и нужен.